# Enter openvpn private key password in a bash script

Tags: bash

I got this function in a bash script:

```
function start_vpn() {
sudo ip netns exec frootvpn openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/frootvpn.conf &

while ! sudo ip netns exec frootvpn ip a show dev tun0 up; do
    sleep .5
done
}
```

It fails because it doesn't stop to let me enter the private key password.
When I enter `sudo ip netns exec frootvpn openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/frootvpn.conf` manually I got the private key prompt but in the script it doesn't wait for me to enter it :)

Comment: I semi solved it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240184/pass-private-key-password-to-openvpn-command-directly-in-ubuntu-10-10 but it means hhaving a file with the pass in it which I dont like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the sudo password you can try

```
sudo sh -c 'ip netns exec frootvpn openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/frootvpn.conf &'
```

---

For the openvpn password you could try asking it to read it from a fifo.
You would then echo your password into the fifo. I havent tried this.

```
mkfifo ~/myfifo
sudo sh -c 'ip ... openvpn --askpass ~/myfifo ... &'
```

Then interactively, if you dont want your password echoed:

```
$ stty -echo; cat >~/myfifo; stty echo
type your password
type control-D for eof
```

Comment: mmm it says me : 
Broadcast message from root@bigbenn (Mon 2015-07-13 14:08:19 CEST):

Password entry required for 'Enter Private Key Password:' (PID 7373).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was sudo. I added a suggestion for openvpn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to enter automatically both passwords on a Linux/Ubuntu-system. (The sudo-pw and the openvpn-pw.)

In the file `/home/user_name/.bashrc` I added the row:

```
alias run_openvpn='sudo date < /path/to/sudo_pw_file && sudo openvpn --config /path/to/key_file --askpass /path/to/private_key_file'
```

In the files sudo_pw_file and private_key_file the passwords are stored in plain text. So there is a security risk involved.

Then you can execute `exec bash` from the terminal.

From then onwards you may establish the vpn-connection from the terminal with `run_openvpn`.

The `sudo date` I used to enter the sudo-password in a preliminary step so that it is not asked for in the other command.

Btw: you may configure your vpn-connection as well with `> settings > network` but they interfere if I start to vpn-connections from there. So I start one from terminal and one from there.