# Use STDOUT as input for openvpn auth-user-pass

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting, openvpn

I am writing a bash script to automatically connect to VPNBook's free openvpn service. I gather the username and password by calling a python script which currently just prints them to STDOUT.

The python script to gather the username and password is:

```
#!/bin/python

# title:                       vpnbook-user-pass©                    
# description:                 Gather vpnbooks username - password combinantion
# author:                      jack herer                    
# date:                        Tuesday 06 October 2015 @ 10:29:14 am
# version:                     v1.0                          
# usage:                       python vpnbook-user-pass                    
# notes:                       ~                             
# bash version:                4.3.30(1)-release             
#========================================                               
# Copyright © | jack herer | 2015 
#========================================

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://vpnbook.com/freevpn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pricing = soup.find(id = 'pricing')
first_column = pricing.find('div', {'class': 'one-third'})
for li in first_column.find('ul', {'class': 'disc'}):
    if 'username' in str(li).lower():
        username = li.find('strong').text
print('The username and password combinantion is:')
print(username)

response = requests.get('http://vpnbook.com/freevpn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pricing = soup.find(id = 'pricing')
first_column = pricing.find('div', {'class': 'one-third'})
for li in first_column.find('ul', {'class': 'disc'}):
    if 'password' in str(li).lower():
        password = li.find('strong').text
print(password)
```

The STDOUT of the python script is:

```
The username and password combinantion is:
vpnbook  
JE5Raphu
```

The bash script so far:

```
# !/bin/bash - 

# title:                       auto-vpn©                    
# description:                 Automatically connect to vpnbook's free vpn service
# author:                      jack herer                    
# date:                        Thursday 08 October 2015 @ 11:49:21 am
# version:                     v1.0                          
# usage:                       ./auto-vpn                    
# notes:                       ~                             
# bash version:                4.3.30(1)-release             
#========================================                               
# Copyright © | jack herer | 2015 
#========================================

userpass=$(python ~/vpnbook-user-pass)
echo "${userpass} "
cd $HOME/vpnbook/
openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn
```

The last command `openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn` then runs and asks me to input a username and password like this:

```
Thu Oct  8 13:20:28 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.4 i586-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Thu Oct  8 13:20:28 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: 
Enter Auth Password:
```

How can I get my script to input the username and password that is gathered with the python script?

I don't mind whether this is a bash or python script all options are open, but must be in bash or python.

Comment: Have a look at [`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `--auth-user-pass` option ([here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html)).

The probably easiest way for you is to remove the line with *"The username and password combinantion is:"* from your python script and start `openvpn` from `bash` this way (works for me):

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn --auth-user-pass <( python ~/vpnbook-user-pass )
```

---

Generally, something like:

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn --auth-user-pass <( echo -e "${userName}\n${password}" )
```

*should* work as well (works for me).

---

Alternatively you can save the credentials to a file (make sure it is not world-readable) and pass this file as an argument after `--auth-user-pass`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240184/5128464).

EDIT>

Confirmed this as working (for me):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://vpnbook.com/freevpn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pricing = soup.find(id = 'pricing')
first_column = pricing.find('div', {'class': 'one-third'})
for li in first_column.find('ul', {'class': 'disc'}):
    if 'username' in str(li).lower():
        username = li.find('strong').text
    if 'password' in str(li).lower():
        password = li.find('strong').text
print(username)
print(password)
```

Used in bash:

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn --auth-user-pass <( ./fvpn3.py )
```

---

Output of `openvpn --version`:

> OpenVPN 2.3.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL]
>   [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
>   library versions: OpenSSL
>   1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, LZO 2.08
>   Originally developed by James Yonan
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2010 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. 
>   Compile time defines: enable_crypto=yes enable_debug=yes
>   enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no
>   enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown
>   enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=yes
>   enable_fragment=yes enable_http_proxy=yes enable_iproute2=yes
>   enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_lzo_stub=no
>   enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multi=yes
>   enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_password_save=yes
>   enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes
>   enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes
>   enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no
>   enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes
>   enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_small=no enable_socks=yes
>   enable_ssl=yes enable_static=yes enable_strict=no
>   enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_win32_dll=yes
>   enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_crypto_library=openssl
>   with_gnu_ld=yes with_ifconfig_path=/sbin/ifconfig
>   with_iproute_path=/sbin/ip with_mem_check=no
>   with_plugindir='${prefix}/lib/openvpn' with_route_path=/sbin/route
>   with_sysroot=no
>   git revision: refs/heads/jessie/b35ad09bfc4a26e7

(Please note the `enable_password_save=yes`)

Output of `bash --version`:

> GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
>   Copyright
>   (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL
>   version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

Good luck!

Comment: The first of your options seems like it would be best but it gives error `Fri Oct  9 15:07:22 2015 SENT CONTROL [vpnbook.com]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Oct  9 15:07:23 2015 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
Fri Oct  9 15:07:23 2015 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
`

Comment: Have you removed the `print('The username and password combinantion is:')` line (i.e. has the python output the correct format)? Maybe adding `--verb 3` could show the credentials used (it should, according to [errlevel.h](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/browser/errlevel.h?rev=818a204bc86d24763baf9b22b26d2b61c3fd1cab))

Comment: yes I removed the line and `--verb 3` produced identical output.

Comment: @vip thanks i will work on this today and let you know how I get on again.. Thankyou

Comment: @jamiejackherer have you succeeded?